# How to resize the primary Windows XP partition?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning

I just cloned my failing 250 GB hard drive onto a 500 GB hard drive (so I wouldn't have to re-install everything, etc.), but now the drive only thinks it is 250 GB. How do I tell it about the other 250 GB of space available on the drive? Preferably I'd like to just resize the partition so it takes all 500 GB of space, but I'd settle for mapping the other 250 GB to another drive letter.

This is in Windows XP.

Comment: If you run diskmgmt.msc does it show unformatted space on the disk?

Comment: Note that special care is needed when migrating to an SSD disk.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot resize Windows system partition while being booted from that partition, so you should use an external tool for this purpose.

Personally, I prefer [PartedMagic](http://partedmagic.com/): it is a very good and stable Linux-based partitioning tool which you can start from CD or a flash drive. The interface is obvious enough, but if you have any questions, you can leave a comment.

Comment: correction: PartedMagic is NOT a partitioning tool, it's rather like an OS, a Linux-distribution, which contains useful programs like GParted and Parted - which ARE partitioning tools.

Comment: @Sk8erPeter that does not matter to an end user. Being a Linux distro et al is just a side effect.

Comment: yes, the majority of users don't even really care about what they use, they just want it to work. I just wanted to clarify that the partitioning tool is GParted and Parted - not PartedMagic, which makes it possible to use these partitioning tools. :) Don't be upset about that, it's just a correction. :)

Comment: Isn't PartedMagic a re-packaged, paid version, of the free GParted? - http://gparted.org/

Comment: @this.lau_ it's a live CD containing gparted.

Comment: @whitequark, Why do you say *"You cannot resize Windows system partition while being booted from that partition"*, I had just **successfully** shrinked my C:\ drive from 900 GB to 600 GB using diskmgmt.msc.

Comment: PartedMagic is no longer free software, an open source alternative might be https://gparted.org/livecd.php

Answer (score 14):

Try [EASEUS Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm). You can run this from Windows itself, and it's free for home users.

Comment: Is this program really reliable? I don't have any experience with it, but I'm a little bit suspicious of Windows-based programs, when such critical operations have to be made.

Comment: @Sk8erPeter looks good, even Lifehacker has an article on it: http://lifehacker.com/399871/easeus-creates-and-manages-hard-drive-partitions-for-free

Comment: @TimBüthe: and then what? :) The article you showed me is just an introducing text about this program (what this is all about), nothing more. It doesn't prove anything at all.

Comment: Well, since lifehacker is a legitimate and respectable source of software recommendations I thought this would get it some points on your trust scale. Never mind, I guess you just have to try it out, worked fine for me though.

Comment: Beware that it tries to install some adware in there too.  Make sure you click the Customized Install for EVERY option!

Answer (score 12):

You could try to boot from a Linux live CD and run Gparted, it may work for you.

Comment: For example, this is a live cd image from GParted: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php