# What open-source drive clone software out there have you successfully used on win2k3 server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, clone

And, how many attempts did you have to make before you got it right? I'm about to do a 80gb to 80gb clone for archival purposes and want to make the best move here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PartedMagic](http://partedmagic.com), [of course](https://superuser.com/questions/215557/how-to-resize-the-primary-windows-xp-partition/215561#215561). It works equally well with any Windows partitions.

Comment: I see that clonezilla and partclone are applications in this distro. Which do you use?   http://partedmagic.com/programs.html

Comment: Well, if you only want to copy a partition to another (maybe external) drive, you can simply use GParted. That's easy and reliable.

Comment: I did the flash drive version, used G4L's click-to-clone and it worked the first time with no problems at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> What open-source drive clone software out there have you successfully used on win2k3 server?

I have conducted large-scale network-based cloning tasks with [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/).

> And, how many attempts did you have to make before you got it right? I'm about to do a 80gb to 80gb clone for archival purposes and want to make the best move here.

I would like to approach your "80GB-to-80GB" enquiry from a few perspectives:

### 1. Archiving

Typically, the cloned images will be stuffed into a USB-pluggable hard disk for instant access and portability (it also supports multiple storage destinations but I will explain that in **Replication**). You can choose to archive a single NTFS partition, or the entire disk itself. It provides verbose options on data compression for the cloned image, allowing you to decide between space-saving and performance requirements that you may be considering on. It also supports a whole lot of other filesystems that you will never be remotely interested in.

### 2. Replication

It offers you options to replicate the cloned image from various sources - SSHFS, NFS, SAMBA, FTP etc. You have a idling *nix system? Or extra space on your XP desktop? The options that are available will allow you to convert those machines as a central repository for you to retrieve the clone images from. It will allow you to conduct replication tasks to a dozen or more computers with ease. Of course, you can always work from a single USB-pluggable hard disk.

### 3. Difficulty

The understanding of difficulty in the usage of a certain application/software/solution is rather subjective. A little bit of reading and you will be all set to walk on your own. :-)

Comment: Amazing. Right after I posted this question, I found clonezilla and began cloning. Everything was working swimmingly, or so I thought. When I booted the server on the clone and logged in, it immediately logged me right back out. What's up with that?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the server via safe mode?

Comment: Even more amazing is that now I've got beep codes 1-3-2 and led's codes showing "system board failure." This is a Dell PE 850 I got off ebay. Blast! What exactly would getting into safe mode do for me if I could get there?

Comment: Did you see camilohe's answer? that trap 3 describes what was happening exactly. That article was about VM's though and I'm not sure if the "disk signature" is a factor or not. You said you've done w2k3 server though, right?

Comment: boot failure resolved (bad ram stick). what about safe mode and trap 3 disk signature? (above)

Answer (score 0):

Ive had pretty good luck with [DriveImage XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm)

Comment: too bad it's not open source

Answer (score 0):

You could try selfimage, odin, diskimage or clonedisk (not oss just freeware). About your log-in problem check http://www.drivesnapshot.de/en/virtual.htm trap3.