# How to un-partition a drive on windows 7

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I bought this laptop used from a friend. The laptop has 500gb of storage; however, the drive is partioned. The C: drive has an allocated space of 50gb whereas the D: (TEMP_PART01) partition has 396gb allocated to it. How do i either take some of the space from the D: partition and move it to the C: drive, or get rid of that partition?

I've done some searching and people say I'm supposed to be able to use "Disc Management" to "delete volume," but when i right click on the partition the "delete volume" is not enabled. Here is a picture:

[image: Dist Management]

Comment: Well i figure my chances of finding someone in this community who will know how to help are very high.

Comment: I also thought it wouldn't belong here, but since the tags do exist, I thought I could answer it even though I never saw another hardware question before. Mea culpa.

Comment: probably d: is locked due to "Page File". Move the page file into c:

Comment: 1. backup your data. 2 play with fire. 3. (optional) restore valuable data you just accidentally destroyed.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/215557/how-to-resize-the-primary-windows-xp-partition

Don't forget to back it up first!

Comment: [You should try that as an actual answer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc738489%28WS.10%29.aspx), Nick Dandoulakis, before someone beats you to it.

Comment: Are you trying to save the data on that partition or not? If not, remove any files from that partition to make sure nothing can possibly be in use. Then remove the drive letter from it.

Answer (score 1):

You should move your page file on drive D. And here is a way to do some changes:
[How can I move the page file to another physical disk location?](https://superuser.com/questions/237813/how-can-i-move-the-page-file-to-another-physical-disk-location)

Answer (score 0):

If you put this physical hard disk in another computer, so you're not running Windows from that disk, you should be able to delete everything on that hard disk. Another approach: if it's the only HDD, you can boot the Windows DVD and delete en create the partitions during the installation of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use [EaseUS](http://www.partition-tool.com/) partition tool. you can do re partition by clicking on the partition and simply drag to the extend you wish. Before you make any changes to any drives, I strongly recommend to back up data.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the D: is holding a page file. You'll need to delete the page file, reboot, then delete the d: