# how can I get more free space from one partition to the other with a Core 2 duo E7500 2.93 GHz

Tags: windows-xp

My C drive has 10 gb and my H drive has 500.  The C drive has very low free-space so I can not defrag properly.  Always around 7-10% free-space.  When storing data or software I use the H drive because it has lots of GBs but some memory always shows up on C drive.  I think C drive is the primary drive.  I would like to transfer some of the unused memory or free-space from H drive to C drive or make H drive the primary drive. I have 3.21 GB of Ram

Comment: This question is various forms of confused...

Answer (score 1):

Cores have nothing to do with hard drive space. Are your two partitions one physical drive or are they two separate drives? If one drive then download Ubuntu and burn it to a disk. Use Gparted to resize the partition and give your C drive more room.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not always that simple. Moving, resizing or otherwise editing partitions has the potential to wipe out all data. Make sure you have a backup first, a 1TB external hard drive to backup on isn't too expensive nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to create more free space on your C drive so you can defragment effectively.

This is not possible from within `Windows XP`. It requires the use third-party tools that can cause irreparable damage to your system if used incorrectly.

You could, however, use a `System Maintenance` tool like [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) to free up space on your system. Alternatively, you could use a `Disk Defragmentation` tool like [Defraggler.](http://www.piriform.com/defraggler)

If you feel like resizing you C drive all the same, look at [this superuser post.](https://superuser.com/questions/215557/how-to-resize-the-primary-windows-xp-partition)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have not included enough pertinent information... partly because of what you *have* included, but mostly because of the misconception you start off with in your initial question.

For example, I am under the impression that your H drive... or the hard drive that has gotten the letter designation of H from Windows when the drive was first connected... is an external hard drive, meaning it is connected to your computer by a USB cable.  Why?  Well, if it was a partition instead of an actual hard drive, it would have been given the letter designation of D or E or F.  If your computer has two optical drives, and the second partition had not been partitioned at the time Windows was installed, then the primary partition would get the letter C, the two optical drives would get D and E, and once you formatted the second partition, it would get F.  If the second partition was formatted before the installation of Windows, then it would have been given the letter designation of D.

Now, if this is NOT the case, and the H drive is indeed a partition of a single hard drive... and your system is indeed set up where the C drive is only 10gb and the rest of a 500gb drive is on a partition now designated as H.. what you NEED to do is back up whatever data you want to keep to DVD or an external hard drive, obtain your factory recovery discs, and remove **BOTH** partitions, and then use your factory recovery discs to restore your system on a single partition that takes up the entire hard drive.  That would mean you would end up with a 500gb C drive, with tons of space to store and download, and no low space warnings.